# What is the connection between"new" and "prototype.constructor" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This seems to be something that have been discussed by many. But unfortunately, I couldn't find an answer to my issue.
Here is a piece of code on Javascript inheritance (from a book):

```
function Car() {
    var self = this;
    self.type = "Car"
    self.go = function() {
        console.log("Going...");
    };
};

Toyota = function() { console.log("Original called"); };
Toyota.prototype = new Car();
Toyota.prototype.constructor = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.type = "Toyota";
    self.go = function() {
        console.log("A Toyota car is going...");
    }
};
Toyota.prototype.isJapaneseCar = true;

function TestCar() {
    console.log("Toyota.prototype.constructor: " + Toyota.prototype.constructor);
    var t = new Toyota();
    console.log("t.constructor: " + t.constructor);
    console.log(t.type);
};
```

And the output in Firefox console:

```
Toyota.prototype.constructor: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.type = "Toyota";
    self.go = function () {
        console.log("A Toyota car is going...");
    };
    }
Original called
t.constructor: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.type = "Toyota";
    self.go = function () {
        console.log("A Toyota car is going...");
    };
    }
Car
```

From the output, it is shown that the **new Toyota()** call:

```
var t = new Toyota();
```

didn't invoke the **Toyota.prototype.constructor** function as expected, instead it still call the function defined in the first place:

```
Toyota = function() { console.log("Original called"); };
```

A [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) with high upvote count gave a fairly detailed explanation together with examples: it said "**3. It executes the constructor function, using the new object whenever this is mentioned.**" Does the "constructor" mentioned refer to prototype.constructor? How are the following 3 lines related:

1. Toyota = function() { console.log("Original called"); }
2. Toyota.prototype.constructor = function() { ...
3. var t = new Toyota();

[**EDIT**] What confuses me most is why the **constructor** (Toyota.prototype.constructor) is not invoked when I call **new Toyota()**?

Comment: `Func.prototype.constructor` should simply point to `Func`. The constructor function in your case is `Toyota`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `constructor` property in `prototype` object contains a reference to the function that constructs instances of that type of object.  Hope I'm not trying to confuse here.

For a string object you would see the `constructor` property referencing the `String` function (a.k.a constructor informally.)

```
console.log("".constructor); // would print function String() { [native code] }
```

which is why typically we would reassign the class (i.e., the function) `constructor` property to its own.

```
Toyota.prototype.constructor = Toyota;

var t = new Toyota();
console.log(t.constructor); // prints function Toyota() { /* definition */ }
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: What confuses me most is why the constructor (Toyota.prototype.constructor) is not invoked when I call new Toyota()?

Comment: Let me clarify myself, the `constructor` property is not being used when instantiating new objects.  If you need to, you need to use the `prototype` object to do so by saying `Toyota.prototype = new Honda();`.  In which case it is a prototype chain and whenever you are creating a `Toyota` object you are given a `Honda` object.  This is how inheritance is done in JavaScript.

Comment: First thanks to your answer and comment! One thing I'm still confused with: some function (in my example: `function() { console.log("Original called"); }`) still gets called when I call `new Toyota()`. Where is this function kept in `Toyota`? How can I 'override' it? And what does "the function that constructs instances of that type of object" (in your answer) mean?

Comment: @JiajiWu a function [object] becomes "special" when you invoke it using the `new` operator. Special in the sense that you get instance object `this`.  Just try invoking `Toyota()` without `new`, it is possible but anything you assign to `this` becomes global. Okay, coming to your question about overriding, yes, you can "redefine" `Toyota` by saying `function Toyota() { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Looks like the "constructor" that's invoked when I call `new Toyota()` is not the same as `Toyota.prototype.constructor`, and it can only be set internally when function **Toyota** is defined (correct me if I am wrong). Your first comment already answered the question, but since I am such a newbie in Javascript, I didn't realize that until now. Thanks!

Comment: @JiajiWu yep you got it, they're not the same.